# typeorm issue while creating connection in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, sqlite, ionic2, typeorm

When I try to create a connection in Ionic Orm it throws the following error:

> Driver option (storage) is not set. Please set it to perform connection to the database

Here is my code to connect in ***app.ts***

```
createConnection({
        driver: {
        type: "sqlite",
        database: "test"
        },
        entities: [
         Products
        ],
        autoSchemaSync: true,
        }).then(connection => {
            alert(connection);
                let product = new Products();

        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the storage path for the sqlite database in the driver options:

```
createConnection({
    driver: {
        type: "sqlite",
        storage: "temp/test.db"
    },
    entities: [
        Products
    ],
    autoSchemaSync: true,
}).then(connection => {
    alert(connection);
    let product = new Products();
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

See here for all available options: https://typeorm.github.io/databases-and-drivers.html

Comment: thanks @puelo it worked ,
 but i got other error that is
"SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it"
even i have installed sqlite3

Comment: I believe you need the cordova sqlite plugin not the nodejs plugin: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: hey @puelo i added cordova plugin as well but it is throwing me same error,

Comment: i added sqlite plugin using below statement 

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite

updated module.ts file and component file as well, but it is throwing same error
 
Error: SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install sqlite3 --save
    at DriverPackageNotInstalledError.Error (native)
    at new DriverPackageNotInstalledError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:41239:28)
    at SqliteDriver.loadDependencies

Comment: I did find that. Maybe it is helpful. Sorry but i am otherwise not that expierenced with ionic 2. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/169

Comment: thanks for the help @puelo , i checked that too i believe it won't work with ionic 2 , can i create my custom orm for my sqlite table's , do you have any links for that.